# looping to make new variables R

Tags: r

is there a cleaner way to do the following using a loop solution in R? As of now, I am resorting to cutting and pasting, which changing the reference column as I want to result to be attached to an existing data set as a new variable. Thank you in advance.

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
data <- data.frame(c("asd"), c(3))
list <- c("eat", "drink")

text <- c("I would like to eat and drink all day")

text <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
text <- tm_map(text, content_transformer(tolower))
text <- tm_map(text, removePunctuation)
text <- tm_map(text, removeNumbers)
text <- tm_map(text, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
text <- tm_map(text, stemDocument)
text <- tm_map(text, stripWhitespace)
text <- as.data.frame(text)
text <- text$text
text <- strsplit(as.matrix(text), ' +')
text <- lapply(text, lapply, function(z) paste0(' ', z))
text <- lapply(text, unlist)

implode <- function(..., sep='') {
  paste(..., collapse=sep)
}

wordProportion <- function(x, corpus) {
  y <- length(grep(corpus, x))
  return(y/ length(x))
}

estimateProportion <- function (corpus, domain) {
  x <- as.data.frame(extractCorpus2(domain)) %>% distinct(text) 
  x <- implode(x$text, sep=" | ")
  x <- unlist(lapply(corpus, wordProportion, x))
  x <- findInterval(x, quantile(x[x > 0], seq(0, .9, .1)))
}

data$topic_1 <- estimateProportion(text, list)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: My apologies gung. I will work up a workable example. And didn't think I was in cross-validated still. Thank you for catching my errors.

Comment: Could you add some data to go along with your code? I would like to see more how you have your data set up so that I can try to make it better. I am thinking a little bit of `lapply` and `cbind` would do the trick. Talk to you latter @user2300643 .

Comment: Thanks for adding some more code.

Comment: I get an error when I run your code. `> text <- as.data.frame(text)
Error in as.data.frame.default(text) (from test.R!4384e6I#16) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("VCorpus", "Corpus")" to a data.frame`

Comment: Sorry, Jarrod. I've cleaned it up by starting a fresh session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a loop, you have to add the column titles later because you can't use the $ this way

```
for (i in 1:n) {
 train[,(i + y)] <- estimateProportion(train_corpus, train_lda_term[, i])
 # where y is the number of preceding columns and n is however many columns you want to add
}
colnames(train[(1+y):(n+y)] <- paste0("TOPIC_0",1:n)
```

edit: unless train is a list, then replace `train[,(i + y)]` with `train[(i + y)]` and `colnames` with `names`

Comment: Thank you, JeremyS. I received the following:
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"  train[,(i + 5)] <- estimateProportion(train_corpus, train_lda_term[, i]                                 
}"

Comment: there is a missing `)`